# What community version of Jboss is recommended for jdk 1.7 and why

Tags: jboss, seam, java-7, migrate

I need to migrate from Jboss 5.1.0 GA to any other that supports jdk 1.7.
I'm currently using jboss 5.1 with seam 2, jdk 1.6 and sqlserver 2008 r2.

What community version of Jboss is recommended for jdk 1.7 and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually get JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA to run on JDK 7, see [JBAS-6981](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6981). All of the following options will work with JDK 7:

- JBoss AS 5.1.0 (plus the fix for JBAS-6981)
- JBoss AS 6.1.0
- JBoss AS 7.1.1
- JBoss EAP 6.2
- WildFly AS 8 CR 1

The right solution depends on your situation:

- The simplest solution with the least risk is to stay with JBoss AS 5.1.0 and fix JBAS-6981 yourself. We did that and ran with it for over a year and it worked fine. Note however that JBoss AS 5.1.0 is end of life, eg. there aren't any security patches available.
- If you don't want to fix JBAS-6981 yourself you can go with JBoss AS 6.1.0. This should be quite a simple migration because it builds on the same architecture and has the same disk layout. Note however that it is Java EE 6 which means among other things standardized JNDI names. Depending on your application this can have quite a bit impact — or none at all. Note however that JBoss AS 6.1.0 is end of life, eg. there aren't any security patches available.
- The next "stable" community version is JBoss AS 7.1.1 with brings a whole new architecture. Depending on your application that can be quite a large migration — or a really simple one. However I would recommend against JBoss AS 7.1.1 as it's buggy as hell. Note there won't be any future releases for JBoss AS 7.1.1 as well.
- JBoss EAP 6.2 builds on JBoss AS 7.1.1 (AS 7.3 actually) and contains many bug fixes (and some features). You either need to build it from source or get a license from Red Hat. There will be patches for EAP 6.2.
- The current in development community version is WildFly AS 8 CR1. As you can see from the version name there isn't a stable release yet. And it contains a whole new servlet engine, which makes a whole lot of people nervous. I would only use it if you have really good integration tests.

I don't know what the situation regarding Seam is for any of them.

Note that sooner or later you'll have to migrate to a newer version of JBoss AS anyway. To judge how hard the migration will be you first need to know what dependencies on JBoss AS you have in your code.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much Philippe!. Given these facts, it is very likely I choose stay with jboss 5.1 + JBAS-6981 until an stable release come out for WildFly

Comment: @McCoy it look like stable release of WildFly 8 will happen in the middle of Jan 2014

Comment: oh, thanks for that info MGorgon, maybe a should wait a little then.

Comment: Philippe, the JBAS-6981 fix didn't solve my compatibility issues. I'm still having errors when I compile my app with jdk 7 and try to run it on jboss 5.1 GA. Any clue?

Comment: JBAS-6981 is a runtime issue (JBoss wouldn't start). If you have any compilation issues then they are unrelated and I suggest opening a new question for these.

Comment: Consider compiling against 1.6, at least temporarily. Everything should run.

Comment: @McCoy found the issue? were you able to use 5.1.0 for jdk 1.7?

Comment: @Zeus I did, but I don't remember what the issue was exactly. Currently, my project is compiled using java 7 and runs in java 7, we set target/source to java 1.7 in the ant build task. If you have an exception going around let me know, maybe it can lead me to remember

Comment: @McCoy Thank you for the reply, could you please point me to resources which helped you in applying the patch for  JBAS-6981

Comment: @Zeus I didn't apply the patch, the problem I had was elsewhere. I don't remember where, but I guess it was I was compiling using jdk 1.5 without noticing. When I set source: 1.7 and target: 1.7, it worked