# Version of JBoss for jdk 1.7

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

A couple of years ago JBoss was free and was maintained(from what I remember). Today [here](http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads) I see that they are no longer maintaining the free versions. There is a link on the same page asking to download EAP or Wildfly.

What is my next option on getting my hands on the free JBoss? (and which supports jdk 1.7)

Update: From the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20792646/258741) I gather that I can use 5.1.0, 6.1.0 and 7.1.1 for deploying applications with Jdk 1.7. I'm rooting towards 6.1.0 as it is more recent than 5.1.0. Is 6.1.0 stable enough to run the applications?

Update:  I can download one of the jboss from the site, but they are not maintained. To re-clarify, i'm looking for maintained and free jboss if there is any.

Comment: We have been using Jboss Eap 6.3 freely in our enterprise application for the last one year. Only the subscription is not free. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @cgon http://www.jboss.org/faq/ in this link it was mentioned that the EAP is free for development use only. If using in the test, integration or production it is paid subscription.

Comment: @cgon fyi, see the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1.1 is very stable and will work with JDK 1.7. I wouldn't recommend 6.1 since development on it was short and the 7.x line is far superior.

JBoss is still fully open source. The only difference is the name change. JBoss AS is now Wildfly. All maintenance that was going into JBoss AS is now going into this project. JBoss AS versions have never lined up perfectly with JBoss EAP so there was a lot of confusion because they were both named JBoss.

If you want or need to use the 'exact' version of code as the JBoss EAP releases you can always pull the code and compile it yourself. It is only the binaries that require a license, not the source.

Comment: Thank you for your time. We already use 5.1.0 in our environment. I've read somewhere that there is a fix for 5.1.0 version that supports Java 1.7. Some other place it was mentioned that 5.1.2 version has 1.7 support. But, I do not see this version of jboss in the downloads section of the jboss website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20792646/258741 this is the link where I read

Comment: According to the link you posted you need JBAS-6981 in order for the app server to work with JDK 1.7. JBAS-6981 was committed to the 6.0.0.M1 code base. In order to get it to work you would have to pull the source for 5.1.0 and then merge in this commit.  JBoss 5.1 is very old at this point, why are you interested in upgrading the JDK and not the App server?

Comment: You have a valid point. We are already sure that 5.1.0(we use it today) works without much issues, and if it requires a small patch to make it work for 1.7, we dont have to change a lot of our environment and architecture. If we do make a big change in the jboss version that is to AS 7, we end up changing a lot of things, and we are not sure if that works without any issues. and there is a big change in the architecture also(within jboss).

Comment: I'll play around with JBoss AS 7.1.1 and see if that suits us.